# Photo export not working for my site in high trust environment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile, server-farm, sharepoint-farm

There is a two way trust between the two farms. When I am trying to start the user profile synchronization service

The user profile service is working and the profiles have imported successfully.
1.I edited the user profile properties to import the user photos which seems to be working now.
2.When I edited the picture property and set the direction to export. The crawl showed success in the FIM logs for DC_export and the photos where not exported.

I have SSL certificates added to the web front ends. I have also configured AAM.

When I check the use SSL service on the synchronization page I get a LDAP server is unavailable.

1) Firstly does photo export work for a high trust environment

2) Is there any article which can explain the working  how the FIM service extracts the photo from the My sites and updates the active directory in a high trust environment.

3) Is there any article about MIISclient and how we can force it to grab a particular property like photos and run the synchronization.

4) is there any powershell that can force the synchronization.